# SQL Left Join after UNION, error in your SQL syntax

Tags: sql

This is my SQL, but I get "error in your SQL syntax":

```
SELECT 
    pp.product_id,
    p.shop_id,
    p.from_shop_id,
    p.purchase_type,
    pp.product_receive_qty AS purchase_qty,
    pp.purchase_product_cost * pp.product_qty AS total_cost,
    pr.product_code
FROM 
    PurchaseProduct pp,
    (SELECT * Product01 
     UNION 
     SELECT * Product02) AS pr 
JOIN 
    Purchase p ON pp.purchase_id = p.purchase_id
LEFT JOIN  
    pr ON pp.product_id = pr.product_id 
WHERE 
    pp.product_id IN (".$product_ids.") 
    AND `p.purchase_status!=0"`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing FROM keywords in the UNION subquery.  `(SELECT * FROM Product01 UNION SELECT * FROM Product02)`

Also, you seem to be trying to declare the subquery as `pr` and then use it later, but that's not how SQL's syntax works.

```
SELECT
  pp.product_id,
  p.shop_id,
  p.from_shop_id,
  p.purchase_type,
  pp.product_receive_qty as purchase_qty,
  pp.purchase_product_cost*pp.product_qty as total_cost,
  pr.product_code
FROM
  PurchaseProduct pp
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT * FROM Product01
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM Product02
)
  AS pr
    ON pp.product_id=pr.product_id
INNER JOIN
  Purchase p
    ON pp.purchase_id=p.purchase_id
WHERE 
      pp.product_id in (".$product_ids.")
  AND p.purchase_status != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the word FROM from both the product selects and you can’t just define a dataset in the the middle of your SQL like that and then reference it later. You need to do something like:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * Product01 
          UNION 
          SELECT * Product02) AS pr
ON pp.product_id=pr.product_id
```